# Is there a tool to list global variables used and output by a C function?

Tags: c, global-variables, code-analysis

I want to make a list of global variables/macros consumed by a function and output by the function. For example, for:

```
void myfn(void) {
  out1 = in + 1;
  out2 = 2;
}
```

..the tool would list the inputs as 'in' and the outputs as 'out1' and 'out2'.

Does anyone know of such a tool?

Answer (score 3):

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is a customizable program analysis tool with a production quality [C Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html).

It parses C, builds ASTs and symbol tables, provides control and data flow analysis, and constructs global call graphs, and has points-to-analysis.  It can be customized to extract this information; in fact, we delivered a custom DMS-based tool to a large vehicle manufacturer to build a tool to extract almost exactly this information.

If you stick to just the symbol table information, you can extract "directly reads or writes" as in your example. If you use the call graph information, you can discover reads or writes to globals caused by calls to other functions. If you use the points-to analysis, you can discover (conservatively) reads or writes to global variables via indirection.

Comment: @SanjitKumarMishra:  DMS used with C like this can act as a static analysis tool; it can tell you for each function what global variables it might (could be conditional) access. To tell if a specific global variable is must be accessed can sometimes be determined statically, e.g., when the access is not conditional. DMS (nor any other static analysis tool) generally can not tell you if a specific global is accessed under some arbitrary condition. To tell you if a global is accessed conditionally at runtime, you'd need to instrument the code to watch for that access. ...

Comment: ... Our static analysis doesn't do instrumentation but DMS is a general purpose program transformation engine, and could be configure to instrument the code to watch for such accesses. We already use DMS to dynamically instrument code to collect (similar in concept) test coverage data.

Comment: (Sanjits's thanks appears to happen before my clarifying comments, because I copied and edited those comments to fix an awful typo ("can vs can not") and deleted the originals.  Too bad SO doesn't allow you to edit your comments.

Answer (score 3):

Understand for C/C++ (http://www.scitools.com/products/understand/)

Answer (score 2):

You can try also [CppDepend](http://www.cppdepend.com),the NDepend like for C\C++

Answer (score 1):

[Clang](http://clang.llvm.org) at least can do this, but it might not be the easiest way. You will need to interface with the C++ API of it.