# Tool to Identifying Global Variables in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, global-variables

Is there an automated tool for VB.Net that will identify all global variables in a project?

Short of that, is there any scripts that can be used that will facilitate a manual review of global variables?

There seems to be tools for C/C++, but not for VB.Net:

> [Tools to find global/static variables in C codebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436928/tool-to-find-global-static-variables-in-c-codebase)
>
> [Is there a tool to list global variables used and output by a C function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335568/is-there-a-tool-to-list-global-variables-used-and-output-by-a-c-function)

**EDIT:**

My current approach uses the following VS REGEX searches:

For finding global *variables*:

```
~(Private:b+)Shared:b+:i:b+As:b+
```

For finding global *properties*:

```
~(Private:b+)Shared:b+(~(ReadOnly:b+):i:b+)@Property:b+:i([(][)]|[]):b+As:b+
```

Answer (score 1):

fxCop might help, but you might need to write a plugin for that particular function.

Also, ndepend (Using the CQL "code query langauge") I'm pretty sure will give you a report or globals (and a whole lot more).

Comment: My current solution at the moment is using Visual Studios Regex search.  I looked into NDepend, and I doubt I can justify the cost of it.  I downloaded fxCop today and will look into it's capabilities.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score -1):

What are you calling a "global variable"?  a variable defined as Shared (private or otherwise) isn't 'global' at all.

Really, the only 'global' variables left in vb.net are declared as public in a module

Comment: I was going with the definition of any variable that can be accessed at any scope of the application.  So a `Friend` or `Public` `Shared` variable or `Property` qualifies.  Also, the vs2010 regex I provided excludes the access modifier `private`.

Comment: Wikipedia's definition: _In computer programming, a global variable is a variable that is accessible in every scope (unless shadowed)_ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable)